Why is size of my resources_rc.py so large?
I have been adding much code and features for the past day but have noticed way too late that my resources_rc.py file is almost 60MB in size! What could cause such a sudden increase in its file size?
Why is this a problem? Each time I rerun app, the resources_rc.py has to 'refresh' itself so I now have to wait a few seconds - otherwise I get errors about modules not being found.
This is the extension I use for compiling resources.qrc to to resources_rc.py: Qt for Python extension

Fixed, in the qrc file I had:
<!DOCTYPE RCC><RCC version="1.0">
    <qresource>
        <file alias="logsFolder">logs/</file>

and the logsFolder had gotten quite big. Clearing it fixed the issue.
